# Angular reactive Forms - how to remove surrounding html tag?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use reactive custom Control:

```
 <div customFormControl formControlName="old"></div>
```

and in the component my selector is defined as:

```
 selector: '[customFormControl]',
```

How can I achieve that the  surrounding

```
<div class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" customformcontrol="" formcontrolname="old"  ng-reflect-name="old" ...></div>
```

goes away?

Comment: Is there a reason you need this tag to go away? When Angular generates a tag, it's usually required for Angular to function.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, 
I just wanted to get the extra div out of the way, so that I could get the css classes from the component.
Tried doing it your way, but it throws an error:
"Unexpected closing tag 'customFormControl'. It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag."
I schould add that although I do have a certain amount of xp with template forms, I am just trying to make these reactive forms work, and I am probably doing something wrong elsewhere. Wish there were some docs on this (inheriting custom reactive components).

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing a custom control directive and you want the angular control artifacts out of the way, stop using `formControlName` directive on the same element.  So you could change what you have:

```
<div customFormControl formControlName="old"></div>
```

To something like:

```
<div [customFormControl]="old"></div>
```

In your directive, you will capture the control using `@Input()` like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customFormControl]'
})
export class FormControlDirective{
  @Input('customFormControl') control:FormControl;
}
```

Within your directive class, you now have a reference to the Angular FormControl with the `control` property

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove the `<div ...>` tag and just have a `<customFormControl ...>` tag, simply use the selector name of the component you want.

```
<customFormControl formControlName="old"></custumFormControl>
```

You will still have the ng-untouched, ng-pristine, etc classes and additional attributes from Angular, but those can be very practical to use for form validation among other things.